# is horizontal swipe intuitive enough on mobile

Tags: mobile, interaction-design, controls, intuition

Working on a mobile checkout page and would like to know if you'll think its intuitive enough that the user knows there are more products on the right side that could be reached by swiping using the 2 following ways

-showing half of the next item in the cart partially faded to white

-a horizontal scroll bar

are both of these really needed or is one of these enough for the user to get it. if so which one?

[image]

Comment: test your design, since this kind of behaviour varies a lot by age group, technical proficiency, country/city, etc. get random people to interact with a prototype or if it is a live app, release a pilot to a small percentage and get stats from there

Comment: I'm kind of confused by this functionality? Could you please explain the use case any further? What are this further products? Items in the cart or any similar items, advertised items?
The user is currently in the checkout phase, what will be next? If you just want to display the whole list of items in the cart before getting to the next phase a simple list which scrolls vertically will do just fine. Omit the scrollbar functionality, just display it on active scroll so the user knows where in the list he is right now. Scrolling just happens via shifting the page up and down (also known as pann

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question.

It depends on the maturity of your users.

The **scrollbar** is good option to give your users a hint about the amount of content that is remaining to be viewed. By the size of the scroller handle. Showing it persistently need not be the case. As the user is interested in the content. This can appear when the user is swiping from left to right. And display scroll bar for  the duration it scrolls. And once content stops sliding, it goes off.

The white part on right side is **not** good indicator that there is some more content. This affodance is also used to display that there is no more content. Remember the contact list, when at the extreme ends of the list, a soft color appears(with elastic animation) indicating no more items to display.

A better solution could be to have an arrow with the white patch and hide the horizontal scrollbar. This will indicate the scrollable area on right. 
[image]

When the scrolling begins, same arrow with the white patch appears on left too. Indicating the content is available on both the sides.

[image]

And during the scroll, you may display the horizontal scroll bar which will send out indications of amount of content left. And the horizontal scroller disappears when scrolling stops.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I was a user and had that layout in front of me, I would try to swipe using the images first, and if that failed I would try to use the scroll bar to scroll along.

I do, however, consider myself an advanced user of technology.

Having both options will let more advanced users or those who use touch devices primarily use the swipe action, and the scroll bar will allow those who are migrating to a touch device to see that you can scroll as it uses a concept they are familiar with.

If your audience is going to be advanced users only, then the scroll bar might not be needed.  If the audience is going to extend to novice users and people who might not be familiar with swipe actions, then use both.

Answer (score 1):

I think the faded item will clearly say "there's more stuff over here", and the way you get to items partially off the screen is, by standard, the swipe. The scrollbar would be useful to show how many items are off-screen (one screenful? a dozen?) and where you are in the horizontal list, but that's clearly a secondary need.

Comment: A very much agree with your summary of the usefulness of the scrollbar, but I'm not sure that a faded item does clearly say "there's more stuff over here". That part of your answer is very much assumption so that would need to be tested before being able to state that so firmly.

Answer (score 0):

Having both the scrollbar and swiping the images might cause confusion as the swipe directions will be different.

- Dragging the scrollbar to **Left to Right** to reveal the images to the
  right
- Swipe the images **Right to Left** to reveal the images to the
  right.

I would say that the partially hidden image to the right is enough of a hint to users.

Scrollbars don't make sense to me in a tactile interface, where you can move the content naturally.

Comment: I disagree - scroll bars enable leaping to beginning/end with a fast drag. I use them along with swiping while browsing though long pages on tablets. One consideration to make though is perhaps to only show the scroll bar on tap, to prevent accidental leaping away from current position (e.g. while reading a book).

Comment: Fair point.
I guess my issue is the generalisation that touch device are successors to desktop ones. So have to use UI elements and patterns based around a mouse/trackpad a lot. 
When for a lot of people a touch screen device is often their first computer (often the very young or older people who have never owned a laptop/desktop) so we can be free of desktop UI traits and treat the content on screen more like a piece of physical paper within a viewport.